# the ) is missing

Tags: crystal-reports

With this formula...

```
if ToText({@Price}) = "$0.00" then (
    ""
) else (
    StringVar price = ToText({@Price})
    left(price,len(price)-3)
    ToText({@Price})
);
```

i get the following message

> the ) is missing

for this line: `left(price,len(price)-3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work without error.

```
StringVar price := ToText({@Price});

if ToText({@Price}) = "$0.00" then 
   ""
else 
   left(price,len(price)-3);
   ToText({@Price})
```

But the line `left(price,len(price)-3);` won't do nothing.
It's not clear what you try to achieve with this.

Comment: I'm trying to remove the last three chars of the string.

Comment: But the line left(price,len(price)-3); won't do nothing. It's not clear what you try to achieve with this.

I fixed it

Comment: @AndrewPappas If you just want to remove `.00` for every number, then you don't even need any formula. You can set the number-format for the {@Price} formula or any field which contains number data-type.